# Multiple github accounts: what values for Host in .ssh/config?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to understand how the configurations under .ssh/config and .git/config interact.

Here's the situation: I have two separate github accounts, let's call them GH0 and GH1, and I want to interact with both "passwordlessly", i.e., using ssh keys in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.GH0.pub` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.GH1.pub`.  At the moment this works for GH0 but not for GH1.  (E.g., `push` commands to GH1 die with `ERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: The remote end hung unexpectedly.`; `ssh -T git@github.com` works, but only because it connects `GH0`.)

This means that for each of these github accounts I have to have a corresponding section in ~/.ssh/config, specifying which ssh key file to use for it.  (E.g., the section for GH0 will have something like `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.GH0`, etc.)

The question is: what else do I have to put in each of these sections?  More specifically,

> what do I have to put as the argument to the `Host` keyword in `~/.ssh/config`?

The information that I've found so far on this makes no sense to me.  In some examples, I see stuff like

```
Host github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host ac2.github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ac2
```

Where does that "ac2." prefix in the second `Host` come from???

> Where do I find the corresponding ones for my github accounts?

Some of the info I've found lead one to guess that arguments to the `Host` keyword are in fact arbitrary, implying that the following would be fine too

```
Host omgwtfbbq
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/GH0

Host 4.8.15.16.23.42
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/GH1
```

But if so, this raises yet another question: ***How does `git` (or github) know which of these two sections to use for any given command?***

Again, I *guess*<sup>1</sup> that this would be specified in the project's `.git/config` file, under some `[remote ...]` section, but how?

<sup>1</sup><sub>I must resort to guessing because, for one thing, I have not been able to find documentation for the interpretation of the key-value pairs in .git/config.  The closest I've found is the man page for git-config, but I can't find any documentation in this page for the `url = ...` field under a `[remote ...]` section.  The man page for git-remote, too, has no documentation about this field.</sub>

Comment: About guessing: look for "remote.<name>.url" in the git config manual.

Comment: Do a `git remote add omgwtfbbq git@omgwtfbbq:user/repo.git`, `git pull omgwtfbbq master`, and see if that works...

Comment: @HieryNomus: thanks!  Please post your comment as an answer so I can select it

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do the following:

```
$ git remote add omgwtfbbq git@omgwtfbbq:user/repo.git
$ git pull omgwtfbbq master
```

This will use the `Host` alias you've defined in your `~/.ssh/config` as the git host, and thus will use the IdentityFile you've setup.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `Host` line in the .ssh/config file is an alias. You use it in place of `github.com`, and anything that would properly use SSH will read the file and swap in the real hostname, and also use the given keyfile and username, if they have been given.