# Multiple git profiles

Tags: git, github

I have multiple git repo (Client1, Client2, personal).

I did configured the profiles as suggested here.

https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/ssh-keys-with-multiple-github-accounts-c67db56f191e

Now my config file have 3 different profiles.

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal

Host gitlab.client1.com
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_client_a

Host github.com/client2.com
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_client_b
```

Till yesterday everything is fine, whenever I do git pull or push for client_a corresponding IdentityFile is using for the changes to pull or push.

Today When I tried to do git pull on client b repo  `~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal` is going to be used instead of `~/.ssh/id_rsa_client_b` and it's failing as it is not the intended one(permission issue). Not sure how to point to `~/.ssh/id_rsa_client_b` instead of `~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14689788/243245) explains the problem: I don't think `github.com/client2.com` works, I think you need to make a ficticious host `Host client2.github.com` and then use that in your remote URLs.

Comment: @Rup, tried client2.github.com this one, no luck

Comment: @user805 I faced the same problem a few times ago, and ended developping my own tool for this purpose: a `sudo` like layer for operations that need authentication, such as `fetch`, `pull`, `push` :-) You can find it here: https://github.com/yannoff/su-git

Answer (score 2):

As Rup says in the comments, change the `Host` to something shorter like `Host client2` (this is just for convenience), add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to each host so that it only offers the specified file, and make the remote URL something like `git@client2:yourrepo.git`.